# OrderBy não funciona no java

Tags: java, hibernate

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:
um contrato, tem vários aditivos
então tenho minha classe contrato e minha classe aditivo

na classe contrato, eu chamo assim:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contrato", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Aditivo> aditivo;
```

só que eu preciso que esta lista seja ordenada pelo campo data
então eu alterei para

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "contrato", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@OrderBy("data ASC")
```

mas quando eu faço isso ele dá erro

```
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.persistenceunit."contratos.war#contratos": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."contratos.war#contratos": Failed to start service
```

já tentei @OrderBy(name="data") tb

MINHA ENTIDADE ADITIVO: depois tem os getters e setters

```
@Entity
@Table(name="aditivo",schema="contratos")
public class Aditivo implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 2379719760666156224L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@Column(length = 300)
private String tipo;

@Column
private Boolean pdf;



public Boolean getPdf() {
    return pdf;
}

public void setPdf(Boolean pdf) {
    this.pdf = pdf;
}

@Column
private Date data;

@Column(length = 300)
private String numero;

@Column(length = 500)
private String objeto;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="contrato", referencedColumnName = "id")   
private Contratos contrato;
```

Comment: Mostre a entidade Aditivo

Comment: editei acima...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422089/failed-to-start-service-jboss-persistenceunit-org-hibernate-service-unknownserv

Comment: será se não tem nenhuma outra solução? é só quando eu adiciono essa linha sort by que acontece o erro, se eu volto, ele normaliza

Answer (score 0):

Tenta `@OrderBy(clause="data asc")`
Pelo menos é assim que algumas documentações sobre hibernate apresentam

http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-sort